# Bad performance of recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, query-performance

I have a [LOCATION] table, it is a self-referencing table.

One location can have a [PARENT_ID] (id or NULL).
One location can be [ENABLED] (0 or 1).

The purpose of my view is to list every locations, with a new column **[ENABLE_IN_HIERARCHY]**. 
This new column must tell: 
-**1** if the location is ENABLED ***and*** all its parents are ENABLED
-**0** if the location is not ENABLED ***or*** one of its parents is not ENABLED

My T-SQL View is doing it right, but I am having performance issue with it:

```
WITH LOCATION_CTE ([ID], [DISPLAY_NAME], [PARENT_ID], [ENABLED],
  [ENABLED_IN_HIERARCHY])
AS (
    SELECT [ID], [DISPLAY_NAME], [PARENT_ID], [ENABLED], [ENABLED]
    FROM [LOCATION]
    WHERE [PARENT_ID] IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT l.[ID], l.[DISPLAY_NAME], l.[PARENT_ID], l.[ENABLED], 
      CAST(CASE WHEN l.[ENABLED] = 1 AND LOCATION_CTE.[ENABLED_IN_HIERARCHY] = 1 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                END AS BIT) AS [ENABLED_IN_HIERARCHY]
    FROM [LOCATION] l
    INNER JOIN LOCATION_CTE ON LOCATION_CTE.[ID] = l.[PARENT_ID]
    )
SELECT *
FROM LOCATION_CTE
```

Is there a better way to build this query ?

Comment: It would help if you could post some sample data, table structure and expected results

Comment: How many rows do you have in this table? Can you share it's structure? Arу there any indexes?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this view to be fast you need to have the index:

```
create index ix1 on [LOCATION] ([PARENT_ID]);
```

Otherwise it could be really slow, specially if the table has a high number of rows.